# Filter wordpress-menu by category name

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I need to filter the wordpress-menu by category name.

What I found so far is the following loop, which gives me all menu-items:

```
function exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        //if ( $item->object_id == 168 ) unset( $items[$key] );
        print_r($item);
        echo '<br>';
        //var_dump(get_the_category($item->ID));
        //echo get_query_var('cat');
    }

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'exclude_menu_items', null, 3 );
```

I added the capability for pages to have categories like this:

```
function add_categories_for_pages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_categories_for_pages' );
```

But now how can I get the pages category from a menu item?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have found a solution, I don't know if it's the best but so far it seems to work:

```
function exclude_menu_items( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
    foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {
        $categories = get_the_category( $item->object_id );
        foreach($categories as $category){
            if($category->cat_name != 'mycatname'){
                unset( $items[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

What do you think?